# VS 2012 Unit Test issues on TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS 2012 solution that includes a number of unit test projects.  I work on a team with a fairly large scale implementation of TFS 2010.  I have a dedicated VS 2010 build controller/agent for this solution.

After installing .NET 4.5 and the .NET 4.5 SDK on the TFS 2010 based build controller/agent I am able to successfully build my solution.

However, the build server will not execute the VS 2012 based unit tests.  I was getting error messages relating to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll used by the Test projects.  I added that dll to source control and referenced the version of the dll in source control, but still got the same errors during the build.

I installed VS 2012 on the build server as a last resort.  Now I don't get errors relating to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll, but the build runs indefinitely.

1. Is this a supported scenario?  Should I be able to run VS 2012
       unit tests on a TFS 2010 Build Controller/Agent?
2. If this is supported, what steps are required to make it happen?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try making the references to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework assembly **not** Version Specific.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  When I add reference, I'm only able to select version specific assemblies.  What would go on behind the scenes in this case?

Comment: If you select the reference in the project and right click, properties you will see an option to set version specific.

Comment: @Paul, did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: @TarkaDaal, Unfortunately no, I didn't.  I wound up moving my project to a TFS 2012 instance.

Comment: @Paul: we fixed this in the end, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue. We had VS 2010 and 2012 installed on the build server. It's apparently a known bug in VS 2010 - it uses the wrong version of MS Test. If you install VS 2010 SP1 on the build server, this should fix it.

See this link:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728659/mstest-not-working-after-installing-vs11-next-to-vs10

Comment: Awesome.  I'm not able to verify this ATM because I wound up just moving to a TFS 2012 instance.  I'm not exactly sure what the protocol is in this situation on SO, but I've up voted this and will mark as correct if someone else can verify it works for them too.

Comment: @Paul: Thank you! I'm not sure what the etiquette is either, but thanks for thinking of it.